# In R, apply a function separately between columns with same names in different data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, inner-join, purrr

I have two data frames:

```
require(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)
df1 = data_frame(x = c(4,3), y = c(0, 0), z = c(NA, 3))
df2 = data_frame(x = sample(1:4, 100, replace = T), y = sample(c(-3, 0, 3), 100, replace = T), z = c(NA, NA, rep(3, 98))) %>% mutate(Tracking = row_number())
```

I would like to *separately* for each row of `df1` AND for each column of `df1` to find the indices of `df2` for which `df2` is equal to `df1`. If I tried to loop then each iteration would look like:

```
for (i in 1: nrow(df1)){
 for (j in 1: ncol(df1)) {
    L[[i]][j] = inner_join(df1[i,j], df2)
 }
}
```

for example, the first element of the list is:

```
inner_join(df1[1,1], df2)

Joining, by = "x"
# A tibble: 26 x 4
 x     y     z     Tracking

<dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <int>

 1    4.    0.   NA         1
 2    4.   -3.   NA         2
 3    4.    0.    3.        4
 4    4.    3.    3.       13
 5    4.    0.    3.       16
 6    4.   -3.    3.       17
 7    4.    0.    3.       21
 8    4.    0.    3.       23
 9    4.    0.    3.       24
10    4.    3.    3.       28
# ... with 16 more rows
```

However I am sure there's a more efficient way to do this. Possibly `dplyr` + `purrr`? I don't have much experience with `purrr`, but I have a feeling the `map` function can come in handy. I just don't know how to call the columns separately.

Comment: df1 equals to df2 when x,y,z are equal? what about the `Tracking` variable?

Comment: and what should be the resulted output?

Comment: I meant that they are equal on the specific row and column, i.e. `inner_join` would find some rows

Comment: see addition in the body of the question

Comment: I'm confused about how you want to compare them, since df1 has so few observations. You want to find rows of df2 that are either (4, 0, NA) or (3, 0, 3)?

Comment: No, I want to find the indices in which df2$x is equal to df1$x for each row of df1, and the same for df2$y and so on

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
L <- map(names(df1),
         function(.) {
             out <- inner_join(x = df1[, ., drop = FALSE],
                               y = df2,
                               by = .)
             split(out, out[[.]])
         })
```

but I'm not sure if this is better or more efficient than the for loop you started with.